VS Code freezing when opening folder/file on Raspberry Pi 5
I've searched the forum and could not find anything that can be helpful to me, which is why I started a new question.
I have a Raspberry Pi 5 with VS Code installed. VS code was working perfectly until one day, I opened it up, clicked file and open folder and it does not proceed past that point, It just freezes.
I have Pycharm and that still works fine but I prefer VS Code. I have uninstalled it and re-installed it and it still freezes.
I generally use it over RDP as my work system is restricted. I have tried using it on both RDP and directly through the Pi but still the same issue.
has anyone else had this issue?
Apologies in advance as I have only started learning about coding etc for 6 months now so do not have a great tech knowledge or advanced Linux knowledge.
Thank you in advance for any help this community can provide.
I've tried re-installing VS Code. Tried running it in different ways (double clicking the app, launching code via the terminal) and nothing works

Do you remember if this behaviour happened after an update ? You could try going back to an alder version that was current at a time when you knew it worked.

Thanks you Irwene, I didn't think of that

Thank you Irwene, I never thought of that. I can't remember if it happened after a VS code update to be fair. I'm going to try finding a command to install an older version and see if that fixes it. Thank you for your support.

I'm experiencing this kind of freezing when opening a file on Ubuntu with vscode on rpi5

@Naveed were you ever able to fix your problem?

I was able to fix vscode by disabling git. Go to Settings -> Git: Enabled

Hi @Nate711, I'm glad that worked for you but unfortunately it hasn't for me. I've just been using VS code on my windows laptop as I couldn't find a fix for the one on my PI. I might just re-install the complete OS on PI and see how it goes, probably could do with a refresh with all the random stuff I've installed. Thanks for your help Nate
